# How to remove keypad from edit text ,but show keypad when click on edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

In my app the first view of all my screens is an EditText, so every time I go to a screen the onscreen keypad pops up. how can I disable this popping up and enable it when manually clicked on the EditText????
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

This can be used in Fragment Class to move the Edit text up and Scroll till the end. The problem is that when I click on an EditText the keyboard pops up. I think I have to do it in java. Thank you!!!

Comment: set focusbaleInTouchMode="true" in your edit text and windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in your activity in manifest file

Comment: `keypad` you likely mean **keyboard**

Comment: post your java and xml file here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `windowSoftInputMode` attribute to each activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivityPath"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Comment: @VivekMishra, It'll open clicking on `EditText.`

Comment: From developer.android site `"stateAlwaysHidden" The soft keyboard is always hidden when the activity's main window has input focus.`

Comment: @VivekMishra, Let's believe in practical. You can just try at own at then provide your opinion please. :-)

Comment: @ArshadKhan, I'am glad that my suggestion helped you. You can **upvote** it too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the parent layout of you view add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` this will put the focus on the parent view and you won't need to do anything else to invoke the keyboard, it will automatically show when the edit text is clicked